# What jQuery selector can I use to match these HTML elements (requires ":contains()")?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors, sizzle

I'm trying to find a jQuery selector that will match only the element that directly contains the text "PDT" in the following two examples (truncated for brevity):

```
<div>
  <p>
    <strong>(07-27) 21:28 PDT SAN FRANCISCO</strong> -- San Francisco
    supervisors ended more than a decade...
  </p>
  <p>The 10-1 vote, with only Supervisor Chris Daly dissenting</p>
</div>
```

and

```
<div>
  <p>(07-28) 08:59 PDT WASHINGTON --</p>
  <p>Orders to U.S. factories for big-ticket manufactured goods fell...</p>
</div>
```

In the first case, this would be the `<strong>`, and in the second case, the first `<p>`. I'm looking for a single selector that would match both, or multiple selectors that wouldn't find any false positives.

By my analysis, I know the following things about the elements that would match:

- they can either be a `<p>` or a `<strong>` element
- they're the first child of their parent
- they contain the text "PDT"
- they have no children

Given all of these attributes, I think there should be a jQuery selector that will find these elements with high accuracy, and few to no false positives. However, I'm having some trouble putting one together, as I haven't used a selector this complex anymore.

The tools I'm aware of are (each linked to documentation):

- [:contains(TEXT)](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)
- [:first-child](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/)
- [:empty](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/)

I'm not sure if the last one will be useful - I just read the documentation more carefully and noticed that text nodes are considered by the :empty selector, so HTML elements that I'm trying to target aren't actually empty. However, I can rely on the fact that they'll only contain one text node, and nothing else.

My first shot was:

```
*:contains(PDT):first-child:empty
```

but that didn't work. I've tried several other variations, but I'm kind of stumped. Can anyone offer some guidance?

One caveat: I'm not actually using jQuery in my script, but rather its Sizzle selector engine. Therefore, I need to try to do this all in one selector, and I can't use jQuery methods like .find() and .filter().

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Why are you just using Sizzle? Why can't you add a class or something on the server-side?

Comment: This code is part of a module that's in use on a major news website, so I don't have control over the server and we can't ask them to change their markup in any way. I'm using Sizzle rather than jQuery primarily to reduce code weight (~5Kb for Sizzle vs. ~20K for jQuery) since our script has 1-2 million daily downloads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using all your criteria, you could do:

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/CKuYD/

```
var $result = $(':first-child:not(:has(*)):contains(" PDT ")');
```

Note the spaces around " PDT ".

This will return if they contain the text, are a first-child, and don't have any other child tags.

Comment: wow +1 - I can't imagine myself coming up with that selector ever. One thing I might add to the selector is to repeat the above with `p` and `strong` prefixed to satisfy the first criteria.

Comment: @Anurag - Agreed, if OP doesn't care how long it gets, it would probably be good to repeat it with the specific tag names. `$('p:first-child:not(:has(*)):contains(" PDT "), strong:first-child:not(:has(*)):contains(" PDT ")');` But frankly, with the spaces around the `" PDT "`, I doubt there will be any false positives.

Comment: Thanks so much. This works like a charm! I ended up using the more verbose pair of selectors based on Anurag's suggestion - I don't think I can actually count on the trailing space after `PDT` in all cases, so the extra specificity should help.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('strong:contains("PDT"):first-child, p:contains("PDT"):first-child')
```

This can obviously be optimized based on ids and context.

Comment: Thanks, meder! I ended up going with patrick dw's approach since it's more specific and should decrease the chance of false positives. Your help is much appreciated, though!